# Page Refresh on Dropdown selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, razorengine

I am trying to reload the page with the data of the selected user id from dropdown list in ASP.NET Razor Pages. I am able to retrive the selected value from the dropdown but not able to reload the page which needs the selected user id from dropdown to the stored procedure as input parameter.[image]

Comment: Can you show the relevant bits of the code you are working with?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `I am able to retrive the selected value from the dropdown but not able to reload the page which needs the selected user id from dropdown to the stored procedure as input parameter.`So you want to submit the selected data to action and reoload the page?If so,you can try to put the dropdown into a form.And use onchange event,when data is  changed,submitting the form.